# Multiplying bivariate gaussians by a constant

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, covariance, linear, bivariate

Say I have the following : 
$$
(X, Y) \sim N_2(\mu, \Sigma)
$$

Then what would be the distribution of $(2X,2Y)$ ?

Let $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2
\end{pmatrix}$

I think $\rho$ shouldn't change since :
$$
corr(+,+)=corr(,)
$$ and that I should use the univariate transformation for the sigmas, so it would be :
$$
(2X, 2Y) \sim N_2(2\mu, 4\Sigma)
$$
but can't prove it, and my simulations don't seem to back it. Does anybody have a clue about this ? I can't find anything on the internet about multiplying a bivariate gaussian random variable with a constant

Comment: The random variable setting is a red herring: this is just a change-of-units problem, no different than converting [pecks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peck) to gallons.  When you view it this way you should immediately be able to write down the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, they'll be still jointly normal because this is a linear transformation. The rest is pretty straightforward. Each entry in the covariance matrix and the mean vector can be calculated individually, e.g.
$$\operatorname{var}(2X)=4\operatorname{var}(X), \operatorname{cov}(2X,2Y)=4\operatorname{cov}(X,Y),E[2X]=2E[X]$$
So, your result is correct.